# excel vba insert comment on cell with keyword

Tags: excel, vba, comments

not even sure how to ask this question.  i have an excel maintenance schedule(sheet1).  setup with equipment in column A(frozen) and dates across row 1.  when i place maintenance actions on the schedule i often need to add comments.
sheet two has maintenance actions ascending.  a few of the columns are: date, maint action and number of workers.  some of the columns in sheet 2 have the info that i manually type in on sheet1(the schedule) as comments, number of workers is one i always add to the comment.  it would be a big time saver if i didnt have to type these all in.
what i would like to create:
sheet2 has the date that the maint action will take place, sheet1 has dates across the top.  i would like to have a macro find the date column in sheet1 that matches the date in sheet2, then find the row in sheet1 that matches the equipmentID in sheet2 for that maint action.  then the comment can just be compiled as a string of that rows info in sheet2 and written as a comment on sheet1.

so kinda like this.  click button on sheet2.  it finds the cell on sheet1 that lines up with the date column and equipmentID row.  compiles a comment from sheet2 cells b3,b4,b5.  insert comment in the found cell in sheet1.  then loop for each maint action on sheet2.
should probably clear all comments of the found cells before inserting the new one.

anybody got any ideas on this?  or maybe point me in the right direction?  thanks for any help.

Comment: Exactly which part of this is giving you problems? Looping over the rows in sheet2? Finding the cell on sheet1 ?  You can try using either `Find()` or `Match()` to perform the location.  Post back with your code if you run into problems.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not include a specific problem and does not include any code to help troubleshoot.

Comment: i do not have any code.  i was hoping for some help on that.  and yes i need help on code for looping and finding the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the help!!!  found some answers elsewhere.  if anyone is interested, here is what I came up with.

```
Sub setComment4Tour()

On Error GoTo hell

 Dim wrow As Range
 Dim id, AC As String
 Dim SearchRange As Range
 Dim wcol As Range
 Dim fdate As Date
 Dim fcell As Range

If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("aa:aa")) Is Nothing Then 'check for current sheet activecell value in other sheet range
    If Range("A" & ActiveCell.row) <> "" And Range("C" & ActiveCell.row) <> "" Then 'check for values in current sheet col A & C
 id = ActiveCell.Value
 fdate = Range("C" & ActiveCell.row).Value

 'Find row ref
 Set wrow = Worksheets("WEEKLY").Range("a4:a13").Find(id, lookat:=xlPart)
 If Not wrow Is Nothing Then
 End If

 'Find column ref
 Set SearchRange = Worksheets("WEEKLY").Range("3:3")
 Set wcol = SearchRange.Find(fdate, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
 Set fcell = Worksheets("WEEKLY").Cells(wrow.row, wcol.Column) 'combine row and column to get target cell

    If Not InStr(UCase(fcell), "TOUR") <> 0 Then
    mb1 = MsgBox("The WEEKLY does not have a tour scheduled for " & id & "." & Chr(10) & "Would you like to create the info comment for " & id & " anyway?", vbYesNo, " Tour Not Found!")
        If mb1 = vbYes Then
            GoTo updateComment 'Resume Next
        Else
            GoTo hell
        End If
    End If
'MsgBox "cell " & fcell.Address
updateComment:
'new comment based on current sheet info in the activecell row
newcmnt = Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value & Chr(10) & Range("D" & ActiveCell.row).Value & "-" & Range("E" & ActiveCell.row).Value & Chr(10) & "Adults " & Range("F" & ActiveCell.row).Value & Chr(10) & "Children " & Range("G" & ActiveCell.row).Value

    If fcell.Comment Is Nothing Then
        'Set ctext = Worksheets("WEEKLY").Cells(wrow.row, wcol.Column).Comment
        'fcell.Comment.Text Text:=atext
        fcell.AddComment Text:=newcmnt
        fcell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        MsgBox "comment added"
    ElseIf InStr(fcell.Comment.Text, Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value) <> 0 Then 'check if comment title already exists
        MsgBox "Tour " & Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value & "'s info comment already exists on the WEEKLY."
    Else 'ammend current comment with additional comment
        cmnt = fcell.Comment.Text
        newcmnt = cmnt & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & Range("A" & ActiveCell.row).Value & Chr(10) & Range("D" & ActiveCell.row).Value & "-" & Range("E" & ActiveCell.row).Value & Chr(10) & "Adults " & Range("F" & ActiveCell.row).Value & Chr(10) & "Children " & Range("G" & ActiveCell.row).Value
        fcell.Comment.Text Text:=newcmnt
        fcell.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
        MsgBox "comment added"
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "There is not a Tour or Date on this Row."
    GoTo hell
    End If
    Else
    MsgBox "Select the cell with the Aircraft that you would like to create a Comment for, and try again."
End If



    Exit Sub

hell:
    'MsgBox "No Comment"
End Sub
```

so basicly sheet2 has the info for the comment that needs to be added to sheet1.  the cell that needs the comment on sheet1 is unknown, it has to be found.  so I find the column on sheet1 that matches the date from sheet2 and the same for the row that matches the id.  so now with the row and column intersect I have the cell on sheet1 that needs the comment added.  then I compile the comment from the active row on sheet2 and do a few checks to make sure the comment doesn't already exist.  hope this helps someone.

if anybody has any input on how my code is setup or any improvements I can make, I would appreciate the feedback.  thanks.